# WHERE clause in INSERT statement using mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

After searching on Google, i came to know that,
I can not use a WHERE clause in my INSERT query..
But i want to insert a value on column "Book_4" where "Student_ID = 1"

How can i do that ??
Is there any alternate to do that ?

Will be Thankful to You !

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO issued_books (Book_4) VALUES ('$IssuedBookNumber')" ;
```

**EDITED:
More Details**
Using insert query, when i insert a value in column "Student_ID" in my table. All columns in the row of Student_ID (except Student_ID) shows 0 in my DB.
I dun know what this 0 means according to DB.
It might be Null or numeric 0.
If it is a numeric 0, then it should be updated using the UPDATE statement.
But whenever i'm trying to update it, it never updates using UPDATE statement. That's why i'm asking !

P.S: All columns have Datatype INT.

Hope you understand what i want to say :)

Here is the complete code.
Suppose: Student_ID is already created having the value 2.
IssuedBookNumber = 51

Using the above values:
Result = A new row is created having all columns 0 except the column "IssuedBookNumber" that is having value = 51.

While i want, the result should be:
On row Student_ID = 2, Book_4 should be 51.

The point is, When i inserted a value on Student_ID, all other columns becomes 0 on the same row. But when any of the column on the same row having any number except the 0 (that was automatically came on all columns when i inserted a value in Student_ID). Update Query will work.. !

```
$IssuedBookNumber = $_POST['IssuedBookNumber'];
     $Student_ID = $_POST['StudentId'];

     $FetchingQuery = "SELECT * FROM issued_books WHERE Student_ID='" . $Student_ID . "'";

     $RunFetchingQuery = mysql_query($FetchingQuery);


     while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $RunFetchingQuery ) ) {

          $Book_1 = $row[ 'Book_1' ];
          $Book_2 = $row[ 'Book_2' ];
          $Book_3 = $row[ 'Book_3' ];
          $Book_4 = $row[ 'Book_4' ];
          $Book_5 = $row[ 'Book_5' ];

          }

          if(!empty($Book_4))
          {
               $Update =  "UPDATE issued_books SET Book_4='$IssuedBookNumber' WHERE Student_ID= '$Student_ID'";
             mysql_query ($Update);
          }

          else
          {
               $AddQuery = "INSERT INTO issued_books (Book_4) VALUES ('$IssuedBookNumber')";
    mysql_query ($AddQuery);
          }
```

Comment: That's because an INSERT statement won't accept a WHERE clause.... learn a bit of SQL

Comment: as stated ^ but [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) does.

Comment: we need to know which MySQL API you're using to connect with. `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? Other?

Comment: your original INSERT seems to be failing you and that's why your update is reciprocally failing you. The insert should not be saving zeros, and you should be using auto_increment, most probably.

Comment: @Fred-ii- 
its mysql, using Phpmyadmin

Comment: ok, you edited your original question to an INSERT without the `where` clause, One line of code isn't enough to properly diagnose this. You stated that all your columns are `int`, which in a way doesn't make sense, but that design is up to you. If you're getting zeros, then `$IssuedBookNumber` is failing you  or other parts of your unshown code.

Comment: Impossible to answer this in its present state. You need to show your full code and including everything, in order to know where those variables are assigned. You state you're doing this via phpmyadmin; are you sure about that and not doing this via your computer or hosted site? I doubt phpmyadmin uses variables, least I've never done that, but used simple queries. Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii-

Every detail is updated now. !
Please have a look, will be thankful to you !

Comment: Best I can do is this. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Also make sure your HTML form does have a POST method and that all inputs bear a name attribute with no typos. In PHP, `BookNumber` is not the same as `booknumber`. So double check everything, from A to Z. Good luck.

Comment: By the way, if you're attempting to do this via phpmyadmin using variables and functions, it's not going to work. I'm pretty sure you may have not explained yourself correctly, if that is the case.

Comment: the while loop in unnecessary since they $Book_4 will always take the value of the last row of the dataset

Answer (score 3):

That not an INSERT. That's an *UPDATE*. INSERT statements insert a *new* row. UPDATE statements update an *existing* row.

```
UPDATE issued_books
SET Book_4 = '$IssuedBookNumber'
WHERE Student_ID = '$Student_ID'
```

(I'm assuming you've properly escaped `$IssuedBookNumber` and `$Student_ID`)

Comment: What do you think of [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) since OP states *"i came to know that, I can not use a WHERE clause in my INSERT query"*. Maybe that's an option.

Comment: That's an option if they do not know if the record exists ahead of time

Comment: Using insert query, when i insert a value in column "Student_ID" in my table. All columns in the row of Student_ID (except Student_ID) shows 0 in my DB.
I dun know what this 0 means according to DB.
It might be Null or numeric 0.
If it is a numeric 0, then it should be updated using the UPDATE statement.
But whenever i'm trying to update it, it never updates using UPDATE statement. That's why i'm asking !

P.S: All columns have Datatype INT.

Hope you understand what i want to say :)

Comment: @JohnConde can variables be used in phpmyadmin? OP states or least that's the impression I am getting, that they're attempting to do this in there. question is unclear and I have voted to close as such, till we/I see the full picture.

Comment: It is getting more unclear the more they try to clear it up :/

Comment: @JohnConde May be this time ?? :s

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a unique index on the 2 columns combined (book_4, student_id)

This would be a good query andshould replace most of your code above

```
INSERT INTO issued_books (book_4, student_id) VALUES('$IssuedBookNumber','$Student_ID')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
SET Book_4 = '$IssuedBookNumber';
```

Note: you while loop above is not needed since $Book_4 will always return the value of the last row.

your code will then look like this :)

```
$IssuedBookNumber = $_POST['IssuedBookNumber'];
$Student_ID = $_POST['StudentId'];

$Update =  "UPDATE issued_books SET Book_4='$IssuedBookNumber' WHERE Student_ID= '$Student_ID'";
mysql_query ($Update);
```

Things you should consider,

1. Switch to using PDO or mysqli
2. Escape your variables are your code is vulnerable to a SQL injection. Perhaps after you switch to PDO or mysqli you can use prepare statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO issued_books (Book_4, Student_ID)
           VALUES ('$IssuedBookNumber', '$Student_ID')"
```

Comment: @@kojow7 row has been already inserted. cannot insert students_id once again with same id. He needs to update the row.

Comment: @KirsSudh how do you know the row has already been inserted? Maybe the ID is in another table and this table uses a foreign key link to it. The OP never provided enough information to know one way or the other.

Comment: thats true, @Mustaasam did not ask correctly. It's a guess, he is using `where` clause in `insert` statement, perhaps he is searching for a row and inserting into `null` `Book_4` column. So we thought he might be updating.

Answer (score 0):

Use `update` statement.

```
update issued_books set Book_4 = $IssuedBookNumber
where Student_ID = '$Student_ID'
```

Comment: Using insert query, when i insert a value in column "Student_ID" in my table. All columns in the row of Student_ID (except Student_ID) shows 0 in my DB.
I dun know what this 0 means according to DB.
It might be Null or numeric 0.
If it is a numeric 0, then it should be updated using the UPDATE statement.
But whenever i'm trying to update it, it never updates using UPDATE statement. That's why i'm asking !

P.S: All columns have Datatype INT.

Hope you understand what i want to say :)

Comment: you have set all column's dtype as `INT`? What type of values you have in `Book_4` columns?. use `update` statement to update if `student_id` column is already inserted.

Comment: Yes, all dtypes are INT.
Book_4 are also integers.
I've tried UPDATE, but not working !

Comment: use `update` statement if the `Student_id` column has been already inserted. Add `where` clause without fail while using `update` statement. EDITED::- what is the value you are trying to update in `Books_4`?

Comment: Thank you for your patience, details are updated now. :)